# Using mod_expires conditionally depending on an environment variable

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables, apache-2.2

I've borrowed some `mod_expires` code from the HTML5 Boilerplate that adds some sensible defaults for asset expiry (I have filename version revving configured with htaccess so I can add mtimes before asset extensions like `script.123456789.js`):

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

# Data interchange
ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

# ... etc ...
```

However, I'd like to disable these on my development server (which sets a `DEVELOPMENT=1` environment variable). Is it possible to conditionally disable `mod_expires` (perhaps `ExpiresActive On`) in 2.4.4 like you can with `mod_access` if an environment variable is set (`Allow from env=DEVELOPMENT`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any easy way of doing this based on the value of an environment variable.  You might be able to figure out a way with mod_rewrite, but it would be ugly.

An easier method is to have your development server set a command-line switch, `-DDEVELOPMENT`, for Apache, instead of (or in addition to) the environment variable.  Then the Apache config becomes trivial:

```
<IfDefine !DEVELOPMENT>
ExpiresActive on
...
</IfDefine>
```

The right place to set the switch depends on your distro.  In Debian & family, you set

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS=-DDEVELOPMENT
```

in /etc/apache2/envvars.  In RHEL, you set

```
OPTIONS=-DDEVELOPMENT
```

in /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

Comment: +1 This is genius! Plus it's part of the core so my host won't choke on `<IfDefine>`. Many thanks!

Comment: Good :)  One thing to add is that command-line switches apply to all virtual hosts on your server.  But for something general like `-DDEVELOPMENT` that's probably fine.